# Installing Cutter on Redhat

Tags: linux, tcp, ip, redhat, tcpdump

I am trying to install the cutter. I got the source code from there site and compiled it.
when I run the cutter I get an error.

openning /proc/net/ip_conntrack: No such file or directory

I tried to run the command 
    sudo modprobe ip_conntrack

but still i get the same error.

Please, Help!!

Thanks.

Comment: There's some useful troubleshooting going on here:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cutter/+bug/240147

Answer (score 0):

Which redhut version you are using ??

The modules isn't called ip_conntrack but nf_conntrack_ipv4.
Try `sudo modprobe nf_conntrack_ipv4` and then install cutter

Comment: Thanks...I have Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.2 (Santiago). I already installed the cutter. Ran sudo modprobe nf_conntrack_ipv4, but it did not help.

Comment: I installed cutter after running the command, but it didnot help. Thanks