# Python socket library thinks socket is open when it's not

Tags: python, linux, sockets, networking

I'm working with a bit of Python that looks like this:

```
HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 43434
single = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    single.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as e:
    # Print an error, exit.
```

While it's been functioning well in the past, we now get the error `[Errno 98] Address already in use`.  The SIGINT handler closes the socket connection, so I'm not sure how it got in that state, but for now I'm just trying to fix it.

Both `lsof` and `netstat` say there's nothing using that port:

```
[$]> sudo netstat -an | grep 43434
[$]> sudo lsof -i :43434
```

`TIME_WAIT` is set to 60 seconds, according to `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout`, but the error occurs even hours after last run successfully.

I've tried (temporarily) setting `REUSEADDR` (via `single.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)`), but that appears to have no effect.

What in tarnation is going on?  Will I ever be able to use this port again without having to reboot the machine?

Comment: Did you call `setsockopt` before you called `bind`?

Comment: @WaleedKhan Yep; it went right before the `try`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: 
tcpkill -i eth0 port 43434

Comment: Running tcpkill (which is in the dsniff package, btw), just hangs on `tcpkill: listening on eth0 [port 43434]`.  I tried running it with `-9`, same thing.

Comment: I also tried using `cxkill`, which reported no connections on that port.  And I'm attempting to use `cutter`, but [there are problems](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11581814/120999) getting that running on CentOS.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add a comment but It will not let me do so.  so I have to answer this way.  In my experience I have had to do the following to get sockets to work with any success.  I've had to explicitly set the timeout myself.

In your code before you open the socket, you should set this if you are using python version 2.3 or later.  I usually start with a timeout of 30 seconds and then tune it to what works for a particular website.   When I don't use this parameter i get flakey issues.

```
socket.setdefaulttimeout(timeout)
```

Other issues I've done after the open are catch some of the following exceptions:

```
            except socket.gaierror, err:
                # you might want to handle this
            except socket.sslerror, err2:
                # you might want to handle this if doing SSL
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set `SO_REUSEPORT` socket options. HOwever, it only works if the conflicting socket also had the SO_REUSEPORT options set before it was bound, so you should try after a clean reboot.

However, you said your python code looks like the code you posted. Have you actually tried a very simplified version of your program to test only the binding ?

You can also try to strace your program.